# gas BBQ leaked gas, now stopped - now what?

Tags: gas, gasleak

Last week went to fire up the gas BBQ for a meal, and I had a gas leak at the regulator.

I always disconnect gas bottle when not in use.  I connected the regulator to the bottle, and I heard a hissing sound and very strong smell of gas.  Hissing sound is coming from the direction of the regulator.  Obviously I turned everything off pretty quickly but needed to cook meat so didn't stop too long to try and fix it at the time.  I did remove and reconnect several times and try a spare bottle but got same result.

10kg bottle, Weber Spirit 3x burner.  BBQ only about 2 years old, bottle fairly new, never had a problem before with bbq or the bottle.

Today I got around to looking up causes and solutions, went to see what I could do about the leak and there's no longer any sign of a leak - no sound, no smell.  Gas bottle is fairly new, only started using it about a month ago, feel very full still.  Put washing up liquid all around the regulator and joint and messed about with it a bit, no bubbles.

What do I do?  Forget about it and use it?  Could a hot spell make metal expand and cause a temporary leak somewhere?

Feel a bit cautious about using it again as I don't know what caused it and it could suddenly come back?

Comment: Did you check for any dirt/bugs inside connection before connecting or after?  It sounds like something was stopping a perfect connection and after a few tries it came out.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the removal/reinstall of the regulator hose is going to cause you more grief over the long term (dust getting in/ o-rings overworked).

Comment: I didn't check thoroughly for any bits and pieces in it no, I guess I was in a rush and didn't know what to look for at the time.  If this is something that does occasionally happen, I'm happy to call it a day and say it was that, but I did want to check first that there wasn't any known problems or things to look out for!

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - thanks!  I'll give it some use and keep a close eye on it for now, hopefully won't have to change anything!